# Counting / Listing Files in the app folder Ionic 3

Tags: file, ionic3, counting

Im new at ionic and I'm trying to make a simple app with a good amount of image files.

I would like to get the number of files in the www/assets/imgs folder. The thing is, I don't know if I can even use the ionic-native 'File' plugin for this since its supposed to be for files in the device. Also I understand cordova related plugins don't work unless I test it on a physical device? I've been using the following code and get the error Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available.

```
 fileCounter() { 
this.imgPathCounter = "../../assets/imgs/tests/test_1";
this.imgFile = "questions";
this.file.listDir(this.imgPathCounter, this.imgFile).then((list) => this.numberOfTests = list.length);
}
```

I'm just interested in the number of files, the content/names don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found answer by far, for others that have the same question:
You should try on an **emulator/device**.

and if you want to just count files do something like:

```
list.filter(item => !list.isDirectory);
```

or for directories:

```
list.filter(item => list.isDirectory)
```